# Pop up application

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I am writing an application that needs to create an object relative to the position of the carrot(**EDIT: caret**) when a user selects a text field in a different application on Windows (i.e. Firefox search box, etc...).

Do you have any suggestions or tutorials where I could read about this?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of editing your question, you should post the information as an answer and accept it.  Otherwise, your question appears unanswered, so others with the same question will overlook it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a great article on Code Project which answers my question. 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34520/Getting-Caret-Position-Inside-Any-Application Great code, thanks Saurabh Singh Gangwar